# What is the kotlin version of getLifecycle()?

Tags: android, kotlin, flutter

I would like to call "Flutter.createView(... )" from my activity which I want in Kotlin. Currently in java it's working fine, but after converting the java code to Kotlin it is showing unresolved reference.

```
 val flutterView = Flutter.createView(
                this@TempFlutterBeginActivity,
                getLifecycle(),
                "splashRoute"
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's just `lifecycle` in kotlin.

Reference article: [Add Flutter to existing app](https://medium.com/flutter-community/add-flutter-to-existing-android-ios-app-ae8c4fb1582e)

As per the article:

```
//Import as a view
val flutterView = Flutter.createView(
    this@FlutterViewActivity,
    lifecycle, null
)

addContentView(flutterView, FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT))

//Import as a fragmentval tx = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
tx.replace(R.id.someContainer, Flutter.createFragment(null))
tx.commit()
```